# How to export jupyter notebook to html with interactive chart?

Tags: python, html, charts, jupyter-notebook, export-to-html

I have a problem with jupyter notebook when exporting to HTML file. Usually, when I export the interactive charts, its features still remain when exporting to HTML file. But today, I had imported some extensions into jupyter notebook by anaconda prompt and when I exported to HTML file, the chart was static, not responsive as before. I have tried to uninstall anaconda and install it again but the problem isn't fixed.

Does anyone can help me? Thank you so much for your support.

[image]

Comment: `plotly.offline.plot(data, filename='file.html')`? Followed by, `from IPython.display import IFrame; IFrame(src='./file.html', width=1000, height=600)`